# How do I create a custom mouse pointer for a website?

Tags: pointers, mouse

I have seen some websites with a custom mouse pointers rather than the normal "operating system" cursors. I know this is very easily done in flash and such; but I am not talking about those websites.

Is it really difficult to make a custom mouse pointer for a normal webpage? 
I cant remember the good websites, but there is one which has a custom, though its pretty rubbish, I was just interested to know what needs to be done to get a custom mouse pointer.

link: http://www.smileyarena.com/

You can see how mouse changes there.. can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could try with css with something like

```
body
{
    cursor: url(mycursor.cur);
}
```